# Can i use SCOM 2007 R2 to re-enable Biztalk Receive Locations that are disabled?

Tags: biztalk, scom

If we have a BizTalk Receive locaction that has been disabled, can we use SCOM to automatically re-enable the receive locations?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against it.

While it may technically be possible to automaticly re-enable disabled receive locations, there are probably good reasons why a receive location is disabled. For example:

- maintenance / application installation
- configuration changes
- blocking incoming messages because a source or target system is down
- disabling a receive location because the source is not available (think of a file share that cannot be reached, IBM MQ that went down, etc..)

In general, BizTalk does not disable receive locations without good reason. Retry mechanisms are builtin.

You are better of finding the cause of the problem, and trying to solve that issue.

Using SCOM to monitor BizTalk is good, and using SCOM to notify operations staff in case of downtime is making good use off the tooling, but you will still need humans in this scenario.